# Search a cell that only contains this word

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that can find a string and counts it.Like a countIF. It is able to count a cell that has the string "skype*" or "meeting*" in it. What code do I use if i need to count a cell that only has the string "skype" on it and nothing else. I want a separate count that of a cell that only has the string "skype". Thank you.

This is my current piece:

```
If InStr(items, "skyp") Or InStr(items, "meeting") Then
count_of_Skyp = count_of_Skyp + 1
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want `If items = "Skype" Then` (if you want it to be case-sensitive) or `If LCase(items) = "skype" Then` (if you want it to be case-insensitive)

Comment: To elaborate on @YowE3K's answer, `InStr()` is always going to check partial strings.  It's looking to see if the word you want is anywhere in that string...If you want to check and see if the cell *only* contains the specific text, check the cell's value.  You can also use `COUNTIF()` as you mention.

Comment: great it works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use countif you can try something like this

```
=countif(a1:h10,"skype")
```